# Facebook Login Swift don't works On Device (But do on IOS Simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I configure in my app authentication with Facebook Login in Swift 2.

**Everything works perfectly on IOS Simulator** (IOS 8 and 9): User click on "Login with Facebook", then a safari page opening, then authentication continue and finally user is logged correctly:

[image]

But when I try on my ***Ipod Touch***, it **ALWAYS block and fail** on this message (*Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can*), and my user is not logged:

[image]

**I have tried a lot of things :**

1. Change Facebook SDK (I have tried to 4.0 Facebook SDK)
2. Upgrade my ipod touch on IOS 8.4, next on IOS 9.
3. Downgrade Xcode 7beta to XCode 6
4. Remove Facebook App on Ipod Touch and Reinstall it

But still not working.. **Any help would be appreciated!**

Here is my code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //For Facebook Login
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    }

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButtonFB: FBSDKLoginButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Configure Facebook
        signInButtonFB.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        signInButtonFB.delegate = self


        //Configure Facebook SignIn
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            print("Logged in !")

        }
        else
        {
            print("not logged")

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Facebook
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

        print("Début login Button")
        if ((error) == nil)
        {
            print("Login Complete")

            returnUserData()
        }
        else {
            print ("Voici l'erreur:"+error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Logged Out")
    }
```

Comment: Try clearing cookies & data on the device from settings > Safari

Comment: For iOS 9 you need to use 4.6 FBSDK as mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x

Comment: I've already tried to clean cookies & data on the device from Safari, and also Facebook SDK is 4.6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my app Facebook was still in development mode..
I forget to set "Contact Name" and allow my app to public access.

***SETUP FOR FACEBOOK APP:***

1. Go to : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. My Apps -> Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email = **Give email valid**
3. My Apps -> Status and Review Tab -> "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" = **Yes**

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. I fixed by checking the login permissions.
Also check again the spelling mistakes of the permission texts.
Make sure your permissions are all enabled on developer.facebook.com.